# eosio_assert do not show message in eos v1.0.5

Tags: debug

After mainnet upgrade to v1.0.5, I cannot see the message of eosio_assert any more.

Example:
cleos push action eosio refund '{"owner":"heztamjuxxxx"}' -p heztamjuxxxx

should show: "refund request not found"

But it only shows:
Error 3050003: eosio_assert_message assertion failure

It made it hard to debug.

Comment: Is there a question behind this? Otherwise you should put this on GitHub as an issue or something...

Comment: Look like they are fixing it now.

Answer (score 1):

Did you use –contracts-console option when running nodeos?

ex) nodeos -e -p eosio –plugin eosio::chain_api_plugin –plugin eosio::history_api_plugin **–contracts-console**

You can do this in config.ini.
contracts-console = true

Comment: Yeah but you can only see this output if you're running `nodeos` youreslf, but if you just push an action with `cleos` you don't get back the hepful error message